# Change contrast of Bitmap image through pixel values [C++ - Visual Studio 2013]

Tags: c++, bitmap, bmp

Hello I have the pixel values of a bitmap image stored in a array. I want to apply a contrast filter over the image? How should I do this? I know that for brightness I add a certain constant value to each of the pixel values.

I am aware of the openCV library but I would like to achieve this without using any external library. Just plain C++.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean the windows api. Plain c++ has does not support images to begin with..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrast can mean a variety of things. The choice of algorithm would depend on whether you want to increase the contrast of luminosity or of chromaticity.

You might try (for example) converting your RGB values to HSV, then increase saturation, and convert back to RGB.

In any case, you can find source code to convert among a variety of color spaces here:

> http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html

You choice of color space will affect the choice of which axis is varied for increased contrast.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there a simpler way of doing it without the conversion?

Comment: That would of course depend on which attribute or combination of attributes you want to modify to achieve more contrast. Personally, I think working in HSV or HSL would be far simpler than trying to modify RGB directly.  However, just off the top of my head, I would guess that if any of your (R,G,B) components have a narrow range of values over the entire pixmap, then you could widen the range of that component to its maximum capacity (0-255) for Windows bitmap structures.  Be aware that doing so will likely change the hue of each pixel.

Comment: Here is some rather loose pseudocode to express the idea of widening the range when working in RGB: For each component in each pixel, get a max and min value. Then again for each component, range=max-min, ratio=(range==0?1:255/range), and for each component in each pixel, component=(component-min)*ratio; That should give you the widest possible range of all 3 components.